# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when using $(element).html to include jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

*I am brand new to JAVA (JSP and JSTL)*

I make an Ajax call to an api endpoint and in the callback I want to load a jsp file, which contains jsp. So, I do something like

```
AjaxQueueManager.get("/xyz/abc/" + efg,
    function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
                $(element).html('<jsp:include page="includes/jsp-file.jsp" />');
        } else {
                getResourcesFailureCallback(element, data.errors, "ocon-wrong", "Something's Wrong!");
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("#####", error.status, error.statusText);
    }
);
```

If my jsp-file.jsp doesn't contain any javascript all works well for example, if I put

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

it works fine, but as soon as I put javascript in the jsp file even the most basic javascript like

```
console.log("hello world");
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
$(element).html("<script type="text/javascript">
```

I understand the error, its cause of " getting mixed with the " of `type="text/javascript"` but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: `$(element).html("<script type="text/javascript">` this is a `jQuery code`.

Comment: Mixing JSP code into the client-side JavaScript like that does not make sense.

Comment: @Pointy I understand what you mean. I am already at the client side when I am trying to make a jsp fetch, which exists in the server side. So that means my design is flawed, any ideas how to fix this? or how should the design be? 

Basically, I want to load some dynamic display when the callback function is called.